# Graph with no 3-clique that needs at least 4 colors

Tags: algorithm, graph

Give an example of a graph that has the following properties.  (Note that you need to give a single graph as the answer.)

The graph does not contain a triangle (that is, a clique of 3 vertices) as a subgraph.
Graph needs at least 4 colors for a proper vertex coloring
[If you think that such a graph is not possible, then prove that statement.]

1.Tomorrow we have a final exam, and this question may on the exam paper.
2.I think it is impossible to draw such a graph. But how to prove? Thank u very much.

Comment: Original question source: http://notexponential.com/477/graph-with-no-3-clique-that-needs-at-least-4-colors  [Just for the record, question was not in the 6212 final that fall!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web search finds https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6tzsch_graph

The Grötzsch graph is a member of an infinite sequence of triangle-free graphs, each the Mycielskian of the previous graph in the sequence, starting from the null graph; this sequence of graphs was used by Mycielski (1955) to show that there exist triangle-free graphs with arbitrarily large chromatic number. Therefore, the Grötzsch graph is sometimes also called the Mycielski graph or the Mycielski–Grötzsch graph. Unlike later graphs in this sequence, the Grötzsch graph is the smallest triangle-free graph with its chromatic number (Chvátal 1974).

Comment: Amazing. Thank you.